# Finding a document, converting it into an object, and identifying it with a variable in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Background:** I have a mongo database named `test` with a collection called `collection`.  There is a single document in `test.collection`:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("64e4a6f9d1d7ba45250dc2c1"), "key" : "value"}
```

**Question**: Using Mongoose, what is a way to grab the lone document found in `test.collection`, convert it into a javascript object, and to identify it with the variable `object`?  For example, we should have that

```
console.log(object.key)
```

returns "value".

EDIT : I have tried the following, which didn't work:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Model = db.model('Model', mongoose.Schema({}),'collection');
var doc = Model.findOne();
console.log(doc.key); // doesn't show "value" as expected
```

Comment: this information is directly available on their [github repository](https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose) as well as their [documentation webpage](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html)

Comment: @cdbajorin: Their documentation has been helpful in figuring out how to create new documents via the schema/model abstraction.  I'm still unable to pick out pre-existing documents as if they were objects, though. No doubt I'm missing something; I'm hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.

Comment: did you defined the `Collection` schema?

Comment: @Felipe: what do you mean?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried? In the current state of your question, I'm understanding that you're asking for a tutorial.

Comment: cdbajorin, I just pasted a failed attempt above.

Comment: `Model.find(function (err, docs) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(docs[0].key)
})`

Comment: placed the comment as an answer so you can accept it if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way (as stated on my comment):

```
Model.find(function (err, docs) { 
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(docs[0].key);
});
```

I also recommend taking another look to the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html), it's always good to refresh the basic concepts.